# Can I use Applescript to import songs from .csv list of song info into iTunes?

Tags: csv, applescript, itunes

Is there a way I can use AppleScript to import songs from my Mac hard drive into iTunes using only a .tsv list containing tag information?

(I have too many files in my iTunes collection so not all of them sync correctly if I drag the folders on to import them.)

The .tsv list contains the following info [where , = TAB]:
Title,Artist,Year.

Each file, whether mp3 or occasionally another format, is correctly tagged.

All the files are held in different folders in one big folder on the hard drive, General Music.

I hope that's enough information to solve the problem I'm flummoxed by!

Edit: Version - Mac OS Mohave 10.14.6

iTunes version: 12.9.5.5

Files just need to be added to iTunes main library, not copied to any folder. Some of the files might exist already in the iTunes library but many won't (this is the prob of having 25,000+ songs; iTunes seems to kick out some old ones when you add new ones).

The tsv does not include filenames, only tag information. Here are a few lines as a sample (you can't see the tabs but there's a tab after the song title and the artist):

> Afternoon Delight  Starland Vocal Band 1976

> Against All Odds   Phil Collins    1984

> Aged & Mellow Blues    Little Esther   1952

Comment: I am not sure what purpose the csv file serves here. If your files include tags then the import will capture those tags. That aside, I don't think that itunes will read and integrate tags from an external source. If some of your files ended up missing tags, then re-adding those with an ID3 editor might be the way to go. Or maybe write a script that imports a limited number of files at a time and then grabs some more and continues.

Comment: Hi @Mockman I have 30,000 music files and only want a select list of 8,000 to be imported, not the whole 30,000. So yes,  if you know how to make a script that would take a csv list and import files from it that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Some quick questions that you might integrate into your question: What OS version? What itunes/music version? Are files to be copied to itunes folder? Do the songs already exist in the music library? Please provide some sample lines from the csv file. Does the csv contain only filenames? Or does it also contain the path/location of each song?

Comment: Hi - it's tab separated (I can't seem to get tabs to be visible on the text editor here!) I realise I've written csv but I mean tsv, I'll change that.

Comment: In **iTunes** I've always first gone to **iTunes** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced** and unchecked **[] Keep iTunes Media folder organized** _and_ **[] Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library**, then clicked **OK**. Next, I'd go to **File** > **Add to Library…**, select the _folder(s)_ and let **iTunes** do the work of importing the _meta-data_. I then have access and it's all organized the way I want it. Is there some reason you can't do the same? That said, how do you expect **iTunes** to import _meta-data_ that does not include the _fully qualified pathname_ to the _files_?

Comment: Not having file information makes this very awkward. What about album information? Do the song files possess useful metadata? Launch 'Terminal', type 'mdls ' and then drag Afternoon Delight file onto the terminal window and type return. Do the results include items that match your tsv exactly? (kMDItemTitle, kMDItemAuthors, kMDItemRecordingYear) Check each song. Do they include stuff like kMDItemFSName, kMDItemDisplayName, kMDItemAlbum, kMDItemAlternateNames? Are the items in the tsv unique within your 'General Music' folder? (i.e. there is a single file that matches each record in tsv)

Comment: By the way, you should consider cleaning up the existing library file and backing it up somewhere before you do a major import like this.

Comment: I should add I don't tick the 'Keep iTunes Media folder organised' because 1. I like to have control of my own file structure and 2. I believe I've read that iTunes has a library limit of 25,000, so I already have more songs than iTunes can hold, right? So my plan is to just import the ones I want to play.

Comment: @Mockman so I have noticed an anomaly in the metadata I have. So although I've scrupulously tagged Name, Artist and Year in all files, one file has a 'kMDItemRecordingYear' attribute and another one doesn't. But the 'Year' field in iTunes has a year for both. Not sure what to make of this!

(The only fields of ID3 metadata I always make sure are consistently filled in are Name/Title, Artist and Year. This is enough for me to make sure no two files have the same info.)

Comment: So, short answer is you can't just import the music files because the physical files aren't specified. You could write a script that would attempt to match your tsv entries to a song file and then add each file specifier to the list. How accurately they could be matched would depend on accuracy and uniqueness. An example complication would be songs that are on multiple albums (e.g. greatest hits, live, re-releases). If that worked out, then you could also have one that managed an import. FWIW, I don't think itunes is limited to 25k songs.

Comment: Hi @Mockman, that sounds like what I'm looking for. If I could get a script that could use that list to search that music folder for each song on my hard drive & import it I think the complications don't worry me too much. I have tagged them so theoretically the metadata is there. I have been looking at Homebrew where some of this may be possible but I've only just about got a grip of Applescript!

Comment: Have you considered moving (or copying) all the files that you want to import to a single location and then using standard Apple Music functionality to import from there?  (When you say that you have all the files in several folders, how many are there and what is the folder structure?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve I would suggest 2 steps:

1. allocate the file (and its path) from info given in CSV
2. add file (e.g. `~/pathTo/song.mp3`) to iTunes

### Allocate audio file from song-info given in CSV

You have to process (open & read) the CSV file line by line.

- [Erik's Lab » AppleScript: How to split a string](https://erikslab.com/2007/08/31/applescript-how-to-split-a-string/)
- [Nigel Garvey's CSV-to-list converter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=125444#p125444)

For each line you have 2 options now to allocate and match the file:

1. either prepare a list of file-paths (including folders and filename) beforehand, that you can match against the given CSV-records
2. search on your drive for an audio file (e.g. with extension `.mp3`) that matches some of the CSV field's values:

The matching from CSV-line to audio-files can use 2 criteria:

- (A) in its **name**
- (B) in its **meta-info** header (e.g. ID3-tags)

For (1 and A) you could use `find` command in Terminal or Bash script:

[Find file(s) recursively and filter them by their path matching specific substring(s) - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/624816/find-files-recursively-and-filter-them-by-their-path-matching-specific-substri)

For (1 and B) there are utilities to search inside an audio file's tags:

[Search MP3/Ogg files by tags/parameters from the command line - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49502/search-mp3-ogg-files-by-tags-parameters-from-the-command-line)

[Output ID3 tags from a group of MP3 files as a CSV file - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18435/output-id3-tags-from-a-group-of-mp3-files-as-a-csv-file), some of the utilities also run on MacOS, e.g. [`ffprobe`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html), [`exifTool`](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/ID3.html)

### Add audio file to iTunes

Is described here:

[Adding a song file to iTunes via the command line without playing the file - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89234/adding-a-song-file-to-itunes-via-the-command-line-without-playing-the-file)

A simple command in Terminal or a (Bash) script could do:

```sh
cp ~/pathTo/song.mp3 "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/"
```

By copying (`cp`) or moving (`mv`) the file into iTune's special folder, it will be imported next time when opening iTunes.

Comment: I am rather a fan of shell-scripting (use in Terminal or Bash) instead of AppleScript, because shell-scripts could also be used on other plattforms (like Linux/Ubuntu or Windows).

Comment: RE: "Add audio file to iTunes" --  The OP states "Files just need to be added to iTunes main library, not copied to any folder. " -- Also, the OP has stated in a comment, "I have 30,000 music files and only want a select list of 8,000 to be imported, not the whole 30,000.", so using `find` is going to be unrealistic because it will be so labor intensive to preform a `find` _command_ on 8000 files one at a time!

Comment: @user3439894 Don't agree: (a) Add to iTunes: the [special folder](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/export-music-or-video-from-other-apps-itns23844806/12.11/windows/10) is watched by iTunes for importing, (b) Large volume of files: `find` is needed unless OP states given pre-condition that files are collectively located in one folder where they can be listed and then matched. BTW "unrealistic" - first make it work, then measure performance and optimize by evidence - read [Fallacy of Premature Optimization](https://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451)

Comment: OP requested —inappropriately— that someone write a script from scratch but regardless, what in the question or comments suggest that being pointed to some tools will accomplish anything? Also, how are the linked pages are relevant. Putting aside that the 'search mp3' page offers only a fuse-based python tool install, said install hasn't existed since at least before 2018. Nor does a batch export of ID3 tags solve anything, especially when the solutions are primarily windows-based. Space doesn't permit me to continue but other than the last link, this answer is confusing.

Comment: I should add that the OP stated that large-scale imports created problems previously (hence this question). So dumping 8000 files (which the answer doesn't actually 'make work') may just replicate the problem.